# How to connect to JMS domain in Java?

Tags: java, jms, sonicmq

I am able to run the below Java code to send a message to SonicMQ JMS queue. It is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037526/post-a-message-to-a-remote-jms-queue-using-jboss):

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;


public class JmsClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException
    {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new progress.message.jclient.ConnectionFactory("tcp://<host>:<port>", "<user>", "<password>");
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();

        try
        {
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            try
            {
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("<queue>"));
                try
                {
                    producer.send(session.createTextMessage("<message body>"));
                }
                finally
                {
                    producer.close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get error:

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Queue not found
```

I think this is because I need to specify queue "Domain Name." Where to put "Domain Name" in this code?

As stated [here](https://jnbridge.com/guides/UsingDotNetAdapterSonicMQ.pdf) the following JNDI parameter should be set:

```
sonicsw.jndi.mfcontext.domain=[Domain_Name]
```

How to set JNDI parameter in the code above?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would use JNDI to lookup *both* the `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and the `javax.jms.Destination` (i.e. `javax.jms.Queue` or `javax.jms.Topic`). This would involve instantiating a `javax.naming.InitialContext` with a set of properties for whatever specific implementation you're using and then using that `javax.naming.InitialContext` to perform a lookup.

However, you're **not actually using JNDI** at all. You're instantiating the JMS `ConnectionFactory` directly (i.e. using `new progress.message.jclient.ConnectionFactory(...)`) and later calling `javax.jms.Session.createQueue(...)` to instantiate the local `javax.jms.Queue`.

Keep in mind that using `javax.jms.Session.createQueue(...)` to instantiate the local `javax.jms.Queue` has *no impact* on the JMS server. As [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createQueue-java.lang.String-) notes:

> Note that this method simply creates an object that encapsulates the name of a queue. It does not create the physical queue in the JMS provider. JMS does not provide a method to create the physical queue, since this would be specific to a given JMS provider. Creating a physical queue is provider-specific and is typically an administrative task performed by an administrator, though some providers may create them automatically when needed.

The reason you're getting an `InvalidDestinationException` is because the queue you're trying to use does not exist on the JMS server. You need to administratively create that destination or change the name you're passing to `createQueue` to match a queue that already exists.